# process webclients data with xquery

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xquery

I retrieve the html from a cross domain web page using asp.net vb

```
    Dim objWebClient As New WebClient()
    objWebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    objWebClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "XPlorer")


    'STEP 2: Call the DownloadedData method
    Const strURL As String = "http://www.example.com"
    Dim aRequestedHTML() As Byte

    aRequestedHTML = objWebClient.DownloadData(strURL)

    'STEP 3: Convert the Byte array into a String
    Dim objUTF8 As New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim strRequestedHTML As String
    strRequestedHTML = objUTF8.GetString(aRequestedHTML)
```

Additionally I want show just a portion of it in a literal control. As an example I want to show just the table with the class "result".

How do I process this further in XML and XQuery in VB.NET? How do I declare strRequestedHTML as XML and how do I xquery in it?

thx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about a webpage (html) it would be better to parse it as HTML rather than XML.
[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a good open source HTML parser for .NET

You could also use Html Agility Pack do download the web page aswell.

Something like:

```
Dim htmlWeb As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb()
Dim htmlDocument As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load("http://www.google.com")
Dim htmlNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='result']")
Response.Write(htmlNode)
```